# Linux Packaging - Program icon not appearing in GNOME 3

Tags: package, rpm, gnome-3

I'm new to Linux, but I just made my first Linux application.  I created .deb .rpm and .pkg.tar.xz packages and have been testing them on various distributions and desktop environments.

I've tested with Cinnamon, XFCE, KDE and Unity and the packages work correctly, but in GNOME 3 I'm having a problem where my application icon doesn't appear.  This is the case on both Fedora with GNOME 3 and openSUSE with GNOME 3, and probably any other distribution running GNOME 3.

I've found that forcing an icon cache update with the below command will cause my application icon to start appearing in GNOME 3.

```
gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/hicolor
```

Installing another application after installing my package also fixes my application icon.  It therefore seems that other packages are somehow forcing an icon cache update, but I'm not sure how.

How do you package an application so it forces an icon cache update and works correctly with GNOME 3?

Also, I've only tested GNOME 3 with rpm based distributions.  Is this issue unique to .rpm or will I have to modify my .deb and .pkg.tar.xz as well?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines#Icon_tag_in_Desktop_Files

and mainly this snippet:

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Scriptlets#Icon_Cache

Comment: That's fixed it.  Thanks a lot for the help.